# error setting linkConfig.connectionString on sqoop 1.99.4

Tags: hadoop, sqoop2

I followed https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.4/RESTAPI.html for trying out sqoop2. But Iam getting error "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: MODEL_011:Input do not exist - Input name: linkConfig.connectionString" on the line linkConfig.getStringInput("linkConfig.connectionString").setValue("jdbc:mysql://localhost/my");
i tested sqoop2, mysql, database etc from terminal and working fine. please help. thanks in advance.

here is the code i am trying

```
import org.apache.sqoop.client.SqoopClient;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MLink;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MLinkConfig;
import org.apache.sqoop.validation.Status;
public class Sqoop2 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Initialization SqoopClient
         String url = "http://<myip>:12000/sqoop/";
         SqoopClient client = new SqoopClient(url);

        // create a placeholder for link
         long connectorId = 1;
         MLink link = client.createLink(connectorId);
         link.setName("Vampire");
         link.setCreationUser("Buffy");
         MLinkConfig linkConfig = link.getConnectorLinkConfig();
         // fill in the link config values
         linkConfig.getStringInput("linkConfig.connectionString").setValue("jdbc:mysql://<myip>/<dbname>");
         linkConfig.getStringInput("linkConfig.jdbcDriver").setValue("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         linkConfig.getStringInput("linkConfig.username").setValue("root");
         linkConfig.getStringInput("linkConfig.password").setValue("root");
         // save the link object that was filled
         Status status = client.saveLink(link);
         if(status.canProceed()) {
          System.out.println("Created Link with Link Id : " + link.getPersistenceId());
         } else {
          System.out.println("Something went wrong creating the link");
         }   
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. As per the documentation generic-jdbc connector id =1 and hdfs-connector id =2. But after we upgraded to 5.3.2 the id's were swapped.
Don't hard code the connector Id's(as said in the documentation). Use client.getConnectors(); or show connector --all method to look for existing connectors and get the connector Id you need. There is currently an issue logged for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1965.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like connector 1 is already exists. Can you try with another id ?